# How do I check if an int is evenly divisible by another int?

Tags: c, if-statement, error-checking

I'm trying to write a program that checks if an integer is divisible by another integer: 8 and 2 or 8 and 3. I'm using `if` statements. This is what I have so far:

```
if(int1 / 2)
{
    printf("2:yes \n");
}
else
{
    printf("2:no \n");
}
```

As long as the scanned number is below or equal to the divisor this prints `2:yes`.

How do I check if an int is evenly divisible by another int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the remainder using the `%` operator.

```
if (int1 % 2 == 0) {
    printf("2: yes\n");
} else {
    printf("2: no\n");
}
```